# Difference in importing Python module

Tags: python, import

Recently, an issue with the Python `import` statements struck me.

**Problem**: I have a package say `foo` containing a module `bar` which I need to refer as `spams`.

There are 2 ways I can perform this operation:

**Method-01**: `import foo.bar as spams`

**Method-02**: `from foo import bar as spams`

The first method is what I generally use and the alternate method is what I discovered. But I realised that the 2nd method is a bit more "explicit".
I would like to know what are the differences between the two methods(if any) with regards to:

- Efficiency
- Pythonic code
- Convention

Comment: @RahulKP while it is comewhat connected it is not what OP is asking

Comment: @RahulKP I believe my question is more specific and somewhat different than the question you have mentioned.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I believe my question is more specific and somewhat different than the question you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding first and third point, [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) you can find all information about it.

> A slightly special case exists for importing sub-modules.
>
> The statement:
>
> `import os.path`
>
> stores the module os locally as os, so that the
>   imported submodule path is accessible as os.path. As a result:
>
> `import os.path as p`
>
> stores os.path , not os , in p .
>
> This makes it effectively the same as:
>
> `from os import path as p`

As you can see it is officially documented that **efficiency** and **convention** doesn't matter here.

As for more **pythonic code**: from my experience, I mostly see

> import foo.bar as spams

I think that this is because of readability, however it depends on the team you are working on.